# Is it safe to use local host and php test on windows laptop?

Tags: php

I am software engineering student and I am practicing php scripts with the help of wamp server and one my friend said that php variables doesn't leave memory even after script is parsed. So can anyone please tell me How php variables work and do they leave memory after use.

I am testing a html form which send the input to php file.

Can anyone please clear my doubts about php, i am new to php. Orginally I am c# developer so i barely know about php.

Comment: PHP has garbage collection.  Your friend is wrong.

Comment: thanks everyone.
actually he's senior, so i think he knows better.
But you guys are awesome!

Comment: Beware of PHP variables: they will send your computer to HELL. Or so told me my goldfish.

Comment: @MarkBaker haha, yep!

Comment: @RocketHazmat - He's not even asking about that. He clearly states that variables persist *after script end*. I'm not aware of any piece of software that can use RAM when not running.

Comment: I do not believe you are a developer of C# applications. There is no need to lie here. This being said, i admire you for attempting to become a programmer. That is the first step to becoming one. My suggestion-- Ditch the wamp server. get WPN-XM instead. it uses the nginx webserver which is superior to apache in every metric. Good luck with php, i use it and it is a far more powerful language than people give credit.

Comment: @kuroineko my dumb friend also said the same thing!

Comment: @r3wt - Don't even bother with WPN-XM - Use vagrant and virtualbox to create a proper development environment

Comment: Any program has the possibility of leaving data behind in the RAM (and paging disk!) when it finishes. If it is very sensitive data, you may need to do something to scrub the paging (virtual memory) disk, and then power off to clear RAM. Otherwise, don't worry about it. It's certainly not going to affect further runs of the server or PHP engine.

Comment: PHP does have garbage collection. If you (and apparently your friend) are new to PHP I recommend looking into the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/)! Best of luck! EDIT: Don't look into W3schools!

Comment: I'd never recommend [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) to anyone

Comment: @r3wt I am really a c# developer, but just a newbie, not that good. but i love to be a wordpress developer, so i am tryin to understand php

Comment: Bad experiences with w3?

Comment: @user3145795 things like wordpress, bootstrap, node-js are the anti thesis of real programming. real programmers write programs and we do it from scratch.

Comment: *"but i love to be a wordpress developer,"* haha, now you're just trolling. 'Wordpress' and 'developer' don't belong in the same sentence.

Comment: W3Schools. Please don’t confuse them with the W3C.

Comment: The link in my comment will show you some of the bad experiences with w3schools

Comment: Thanks, I removed that part of my answer. I am interested to see what experiences!

Comment: @crypticツ Wordpress developer refer to plugin and theme developer. People out there cashing there skills from wordpress

Comment: @MarkBaker or i'll just develop on my dual e2560v 128 g server....

Comment: @user3145795: So in other words making plugins and themes to polish a turd. =oP

Comment: _Real_ Programmers flip toggle switches on the CPU front panel!

Comment: I feel so ignorant for being so misled. Thanks for shedding some light on the horrors of W3Schools. I am aware that w3c is very reputable.

Comment: which is the good site to get knowlegde from?

Comment: PHP manual is generally helpful. I put the link in my answer. Here it is again. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/ http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way PHP work usually is by creating a new process, running the PHP script(s), then terminating the process. So nothing is left in memory since the process has been killed.

Maybe what your friend is talking about are session variables but this is something different.

Comment: Session variables are not stored in "memory", they are stored elsewhere on the system.

Comment: Even session variables don't remain in memory unless you've specifically overridden the default session handler with one that does use memory

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I agree, that's why I wrote "maybe". What is friend is talking about is either very vague or very wrong.

Comment: only cached globals remain in memory. you have to register a global for it to be cached. ex, `global $somevariable,$someothervariable; $somevariable = 1; $someothervariable = 2;`

Comment: @r3wt: Not after the script ends.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That is not always true. I can think of a few instances where it can remain.

Comment: @r3wt: Really?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @r3wt I am not that advance php guys, hold on. I am just a newbie. I using a book called "Head First with php and mySql". I already know mySql but no idea about php

Comment: @RocketHazmat long running php daemon process, persisten db connection on ajax content**

Comment: @user3145795 i recommend the book "Programming PHP" by kevin tatroe. it has an awesome appendix with an explanation of pretty much all inbuilt php functions. its even helpful to beginners.

Comment: @r3wt thanks, I try to search it on amazon. One thing for sure, You guys are really amazing at programing and actually speak real developer language. I love stackoverflow. I hope I'll gain amazing knowlegde here.

Comment: @user3145795 Most of us our amateurs. I made the jump from webdesign to php about 6 months ago. I really can't believe how fast i've learned, but everyday is a new challenge and a chance to learn and grow. I hope you stick with it. Who knows what you could accomplish.

Comment: A book that devotes itself to explaining all the PHP built-in functions is surely just duplicating what's on PHP.net; surely better to find something that teaches concepts and good practise rather than simply repeating the manual

Comment: thanks buddy for inspiring me :)
I'll really do my best to accomplish something big, I've a question for you!
Can you make templates?
I mean blogger templates?

Comment: @MarkBaker No. php.net just shows syntax, examples and a vaguely worded paragraph. The book i mentioned gives a thorough explanation, and possible situational results of operations. it could teach a monkey what a xor operation does.

Comment: @r3wt I've found this "programming php by kevin tatroe and rasmus lerdorf (o'reilly)"

is it the right one?

Comment: php.net also has a host of user comments against most functions.... they're well worth reading

Comment: @user3145795 yep thats the one. if you have a kindle, its cheaper and easier to keep next to the computer for a quick reference guide.

Comment: I have a kindle extension installed on my chrome, so i can it read it on my laptop :)
thanks for your reference! :)